# BizTalk ESSO warning after installing KB-3062831

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I am running BizTalk 2013 R2 on Windows Server 2012 R2 when I saw SSO consuming memory in 1.8 to 2 GB. In order to address this memory leak issue I applied the fix published at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3062831 . After the fix I am seeing this warning in the event log. what's best approach to match required version of SSO DB ?

There is two event log entry found after installed KB-3062831 as below.

1. This version of the SSO server is not compatible with the SSO database.
   The SSO server will upgrade your master secret server.
   SQL Server Name: [My server name]
   SSO Database Name: SSODB
   SSO Database Version: 5.0
   Required Version: 5.1
2. Setting database option COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL to 100 for database 'SSODB'.

Comment: Did you install the Hotfix on all computers running any BizTalk component?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions@Johns-305 !! I planned something like SQL then BIZTALK so ones I installed CU5 and kB on SQL I show etenvviwer on SQL later ones complete installation on BIzTalk all errors gone and it’s working as expected.

Comment: Done!  Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important note: when applying BizTalk updates, you must run them on all computers where any BizTalk component is installed.  This includes the MSS, IIS, BT Admin and the SDK.